# Arduino http request

Tags: c++, arduino, httprequest

I'm sending data to a webserver, and the webserver stores in mysql database. How i return back the stuff (ok) variable to arduino and make a Serial Print(#stuff)?

```
  String request = "GET "+ repository + "sensor.php?value=" + value + " HTTP/1.0";
  send_request(request);

  void send_request (String request) {
  Adafruit_CC3000_Client client = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, port);
  if (client.connected()) {
    client.println(request);      
    client.println(F(""));
    Serial.println("Connected & Data sent");
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
  }
  char c = client.read();
  while (client.connected()) {
    while (client.available()) {
     char c = client.read();
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Closing connection");
  client.close();
}
```

PHP FILE:

```
$stuff = "";
include("conec.php");
if ($_GET["value"]) {
$link=Conection();
$Sql="insert into table (VALUE) values ('".($_GET["value"])."')"; 
mysql_query($Sql,$link);
$stuff = ok;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking just to echo the output to the request? `echo $stuff;`

Comment: I want to make a serial print in arduino using $stuff variable that i send.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know arduino, but my guess is that `client.read();` reads a character from the response. Right now you're reading into the variable `c` and just overwriting the variable until you read the entire response. Try making a string buffer, and reading the characters into the string. Once that is done try printing out your buffer.

Without any testing the code would be along the lines of:

```
string buffer;
int counter = 0;
while (client.connected()) {
  while (client.available()) {
   buffer[counter++] = client.read();
  }
}
Serial.println("Closing connection");
Serial.println("Buffer value is: " + buffer);
client.close();
```

That would replace:

```
char c = client.read();
while (client.connected()) {
  while (client.available()) {
   char c = client.read();
  }
}
Serial.println("Closing connection");
client.close();
```

You would also have to put an `echo $stuff` in your PHP file in order to respond to the incoming request.

**Edit**

You also have a couple more issues. The mysql library has been deprecated, I would recommend looking into the mysqli php library. You are also vulnerable to a SQL injection by `$_GET["value"]` directly into your SQL query string. Look into using the function mysqli_real_escape_string() function in order to protect yourself.

You are also not assigning `$stuff` to a string. Be sure to put `ok` in quotes.

Comment: Doesn't work, logic looks good, but nothing is displayed:Buffer value is:

Comment: Navigate your browser to your server running your PHP file, it should print the value you're looking for. Also look at where you are defining `$stuff`, make sure you assign it to a string by putting `"ok"` in quotes. Also, in your PHP file, you're leaving yourself vulnerable to a SQL injection look into using the mysql_real_escape_string() function. The mysql library is also deprecated, look into using mysqli instead.

Comment: I already try with this "" or '', i can see this $stuff printing, but arduino is not able to read this value, i don't know why. Tnk you for the sql notation, but i will solve this in a second step, because is not my priority right now.